# How can I access Jupyter Notebook remotely?

Tags: amazon-ec2, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have some amazon machine, in which I have Anaconda installed.
I want to remotely access the notebook.
When at home in my private network, I can access the remote notebook from my browser (I have done the proper configurations).
However, when I am on a public network (university) I can't access the notebook (probably because of the proxy).

I tried to access the notebook via ssh connection but with no success, possibly due to user flaws.
How can I connect to the remote notebook?

Comment: Could you connect to your server directly via ssh from uni's network?
I think your problem could be in AWS Security Groups conf. or maybe your university blocks notebook port.

Comment: I can connect form uni group via ssh my friend

Comment: Ok — if you have an access to your server and could check www from your uni's network (which is obvious) try to set up jupyter on :80 port.  
Also don't forget to check `jupyter_notebook_config.py` for `c.NotebookApp.ip`

Comment: What do you mean by jupyter_notebook_config.py for c.NotebookApp.ip? what is there to check?

Comment: Read this: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html